# Align spans of a list

Tags: html, css

I have this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lehqyf1t

```
<ul class="myclass">
    <li><span style="background-color:#f608ff"></span>Text 1</li>
    <li><span style="background-color:#f608ff"></span>Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.myclass li span {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

No matter what I try I cannot get both lines to be aligned properly. How could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap out the `float` for `display:inline-block` and then you don't have to worry about clearing floats at all.

```css
li {
  list-style:none;
  }

.myclass li span{
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
 background-color:#f608ff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="myclass">
    <li><span></span>Text 1</li>
    <li><span></span>Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear the `float` in `<li>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lehqyf1t/2/